# Как передать id ссылки в модальное окно?

Tags: javascript

есть ссылки, открывающие модальное окно:

```
<a id="1" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detail">
<a id="2" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detail">
<a id="3" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detail">
```

в модальном окне есть input:

```
<input name="id" value="">
```

как при запуске модального окна, отобразить в value соответствующий ссылке id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
const modal = document.querySelector('.modal');
links.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    const linkId = this.getAttribute('id'); //Идентификатор ссылки
    modal.querySelector('[name="id"]').value = linkId; //Вот эта строка ищет в вашем модальном окне необходимое вам текстовое поле и, когда находит, помещает в значение этого поля идентификатор ссылки linkId
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a id="1" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detail">Открыть модальное окно 1</a>
<a id="2" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detail">Открыть модальное окно 2</a>
<a id="3" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Detail">Открыть модальное окно 3</a>
<div class="modal">
  <input name="id" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает